# Identifying the set $A = \{x: \text{$x$ is a real number and $x^2 = 16$ and $2x = 6$}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set A = { $x$ : $x$ is a real number and $x^2$ = 16 and 2$x$ = 6} is equal to?

(a) { $\phi$ }
(b) { 4 }
(c) { 1, 2 }
(d) None of these

The answer given in my book is option (a). But I think it should be (d) as option (a) here, is not an empty set. Please answer with a proper explanation.

Comment: I have never seen $\{ \emptyset \}$ used as a notation for the empty set. That said, check your book for any previous definitions of *their* notation conventions, however unusual they may be. Or, get a better book.

Comment: The set $\{\varnothing\}$ is not the empty set; it contains exactly one element. (That element is not a real number, so the set can't be $A$.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right. $A=\{\}=\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$.